# How to make custom script to run in background?

Tags: shell

I have a custom script which runs a java class to update Latest data in Database .

```
cd /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/TradeOnlineChat/WEB-INF/classes/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/TradeOnlineChat/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties -cp .:/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/TradeOnlineChat/WEB-INF/lib/* com.util.AllNewsUpdatrUtility
exit 0
```

The name of the file is

```
allnewsupdater.sh
```

The issue i am facin is that i cannot run the script in background , means when i simply run it as

`allnewsupdater.sh &` and press enter key , the data will be not updated , but when i don't give **ampersand** and wait for it it runs fine

Comment: Does the script expect any user interaction?  If no, then can you run the following command: sh -x allnewsupdater.sh > ./log_file.txt & and then in a new session check what is being logged into the log file?  It'll hopefully give you an indication of where the script is 'hanging'.

Comment: What *does* happen when you do that? Does the script hang? Does it return? Do you get an error?